# Product Area not showing after CSV Product Upload Issue

Tags: magento-1.9, product, csv

I have ran into a very strange issue with Magento, which I am hoping someone here can help with.

Yesterday, we could add products & everything worked fine on the backend. The client ran a product CSV import yesterday, which has resulted in the add products area to not show on the backend.

I have attached a screenshot of the issue. Is it possible a product CSV import could break an area of the database which could cause this issue?

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Console errors below:

Uncaught ReferenceError: product_info_tabsJsTabs is not defined
    at (index):1062
(index):969 Uncaught ReferenceError: product_info_tabsJsTabs is not defined
    at (index):969
    at responder (prototype.js:5598)

Adam

Answer (score 0):

you should enable logging (System->configuration->Advanced->Developer->Log Settings->
Enabled) and try to reimport. 
Afterwards add here the contents of MAGENTOROOTPATH/var/system.log and MAGENTOROOTPATH/var/exception.log

And the imported CSV would be helpful too to answer your question.

I had a similar case where i had defined a field static via import setup script, but didn't implement a corresponding sql query for the main table.

But without more data it is hard to give a qualified answer.

Kind regards,
Marcel